# SAP HANA configure XS Server for multitenant DB (via webdispatcher.ini and xsengine.ini)

Tags: multi-tenant, hana

How can I configure the XS server in SAP HANA SPS 09?

So far I figured out

- "System Database" is the main database and central configuration.
- "System Database" is connected using the tenant name "SYSTEMDB"
- "System Database" contains webdispatcher.ini, deamon.ini, etc. within "Hana Studio" -> "Administration -> "Configuration"
  (the tenant databases do not contiain those configuration files)
- Reading the tutorial [Exposing HTTP access to multitenant database containers in SAP HANA SPS09](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/12/09/hide-and-seek-in-xsengine--expose-http-access-to-multitenant-database-containers-in-sap-hana-sps09) helped me to configure XS for the main database.

Unfortunately the configuration Steps in the HANA Administration Guide - Chapter 3.2.1.8 "Configure HTTP Access to Multitenant Database
Containers" do not succeed. Neither the SQL Statements nor the configuration via GUI seem to have any impact.

Configuration commands:

```
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('xsengine.ini', 'database', ' <tenant_DB_name> ') SET ('public_urls', 'http_url') = 'http:// <virtual_hostname> :80 <instance> ' WITH RECONFIGURE;
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('xsengine.ini', 'database', ' <tenant_DB_name> ') SET ('public_urls', 'https_url') = 'https:// <virtual_hostname> :80 <instance> ' WITH RECONFIGURE;
```

Result command leads to the same results as before:

```
SELECT KEY, VALUE, LAYER_NAME FROM SYS.M_INIFILE_CONTENTS WHERE FILE_NAME = 'webdispatcher.ini' AND SECTION = 'profile' AND KEY LIKE 'wdisp/system%'
```

Also according to [Exposing HTTP access to multitenant database containers in SAP HANA SPS09](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/12/09/hide-and-seek-in-xsengine--expose-http-access-to-multitenant-database-containers-in-sap-hana-sps09) you should make a new entry within webdispatcher.ini -> profile
I am able to edit the existing wdisp/system_0 (which was required to get XS working for the system DB
Unfortunately I am not able the add wdisp/system_1 parameter since "Add Parameter..." Context menu is missing for the webdispatcher.ini

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the mentioned description  [Exposing HTTP access to multitenant database containers in SAP HANA SPS09](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/12/09/hide-and-seek-in-xsengine--expose-http-access-to-multitenant-database-containers-in-sap-hana-sps09)

The main problem was that I did connect with "Multiple containers" -> SYSTEMDB (tenant) instead of "Multiple container" -> "System database container" 
[image]

Further Notes for configuring the containers:

- The description from the HANA Administration Guide - Chapter 3.2.1.8 "Configure HTTP Access to Multitenant Database Containers" has no effect
- The most important part is "SAP HANA Studio" -> Administration -> Configuration -> webdispatcher.ini -> profile -> <add strings>
- String (System): SID=<sid>,EXTSRV=http://localhost:3$(SAPSYSTEM)<part-of-port-for-http>,SRCVHOST=<URL-typed-in-browser>
  Example: SID=db1,EXTSRV=http://localhost:3$(SAPSYSTEM)42,SRCVHOST=hanadb01-db1.my.domain.com
- make sure you have the correct HTTP port number and to use the URL like you type it in the browser
- call this configuration in the browser with http://hanadb01-db1.my.domain.com:8000 if your instance number is 00 (else http://hanadb01-db1.my.domain.com:80<instance_number>